# Difference between Arduino IDE giving me headaches

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny, nrf24l01+

For some time now I've been playing around with the latest version of Arduino IDE and my UNO and ATTiny with simple 433 RF links with the Manchester Library. It all worked fine, but for my next project I want to take the step up and use a better wireless thingy... like the nRF24l01 or the nfm12b.

And then starts the pain. Attiny does not have hardware serial, but people seems to have solved this by implementing software-serial. But then they have to use some other boards for ATTiny, because when I try to run the examples I get error messages that it could not find  and so on. I use the ATTiny boards I found over at [google code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/arduino-tiny/).

Regarding the RFM12B I got something to compile. If I went back and downloaded Arduino IDE 1.5.0 (no other!) it actually work with the JeeLib - hurray! Why is this, why can't I use the latest version of the Arduino IDE?

Regarding the NRF24 chip this case is unresolved. I have not found the correct combination of boards, IDE and library versions. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

What are the difference between the Arduino IDE's? Why can I get stuff to work on 1.5.0 but not the latest 1.6.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get RF24 working:

1. Download the latest IDE (not 1.0*)
2. Use the library manager to download the
   latest RF24.
3. See https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24/issues/236#issuecomment-205354077
   about what core to use.
4. Don't forget to define ATTiny in the sketch
   Ex: `#define __AVR_ATtiny84__`
   (84, 44, 24 are the choices)

ATTiny* do not have SPI, that's why it can't find SPI.h (SPI library).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there was an internal dispute in the Arduino company. So now there are two companies selling under the Arduino name.

www.arduino.cc 's latest ide is 1.5.x and that has more features than www.arduino.org 's ide 1.6.x. So make sure you use arduino.cc's version only because they do the major development of the IDE.